# Suggest a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 fields.

```
ID    Name     ParentID     Active
1     A        0            1
2     B        0            1
3     C        2            1
```

Now, I want a query where if there is row with `ParentID` > 0 and active then the row with its parent id (2) is skipped.

Please suggest a single MySQL query to achieve this.

Thank you,
Khuram

Edit: Thanks guys, finally solved and marked the correct answer.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: If you rewrite your question from the perspective of the parent row (that should be omitted) you will have a reasonable start for an implementation.

Comment: Believe me, we are well adapt at writing queries but this one stumps my mind. Maybe something with MySQL Case>

Comment: By the way, you might find this useful in the future, for setting up queries so that people can have a play with your schema/data: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @nnichols thanks guys. I will keep in mind and review my previous questions as well. Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work :

```
select * from test where id not in ( select parent_id from test where parent_id > 0 and active = 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE (NOT ParentID > 0 AND Active=1) OR Active=0
```

Comment: but if row 3 is Inactive then automatically Row 2 should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the question is very clear. Do you mean read all rows where their ID is not in a parent column whose row is active? If so:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT ParentID FROM mytable WHERE Active = 1
);
```

Comment: if Row 3 is active then select 1,3 and if row 3 is inactive then select 1,2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ParentID
    AND t2.Active = 1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```